# Custom windows hint on buttons in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, hint

I would like to make a custom formatted Hint for some buttons in my application.
I use to make a tadvtoolpanel and display it on the onmousemove event, but it is not very clean.

Is there a button (from TMS component for example) which enables this directly ?
I just want the user to have a quick resume windows on the mousemove on it.

Hope i manage to explain clearly.

Thanks
Gwenael

Comment: I also tried with THTMLHint, but i don't manage to use it, all help will be welcome ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use [TAdvOfficeHint](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/atbdev2.asp) from TMS and just drop it on your mainform. All the TMS buttons have an `OfficeHint` property that lets you specify the title, text and icon of the hint. If no office hint is specified, the normal `Hint` property is used.

Comment: And how can i display a HTML texte to personnalise my hint text so ?

Comment: Do u know a lot about TMS component so ?? got questions on DBAdvGrid, how to color lines with different colors depending on cell values for example. Thakns

Comment: @Gwenael - don't forget to accept the answers [this way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if they solved your questions.

Comment: @Gwenael - no, I don't use DBAdvGrid. Just ask here on SO if you have specific questions. I'm pretty sure someone will be able to help you.